# Get WooCommerce statuses that are available for admin to change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a custom order's page, and I need to recreate a bulk action dropdown from WooCommerce orders page. `wc_get_order_statuses()` gives me array of all the WooCommerce order statuses which is not quite what I need.

```
Array (
    [wc-pending] => Pending payment
    [wc-processing] => Processing
    [wc-on-hold] => On hold
    [wc-completed] => Completed
    [wc-cancelled] => Cancelled
    [wc-refunded] => Refunded
    [wc-failed] => Failed
    [wc-customer-edit] => Customer Edit
)
```

It has `Failed`, `Refunded` and `Cancelled` order status that are applied automatically in certain events. Is there a way to get all order status that admin is allowed to set in WooCommerce excluding the automated ones?

Comment: I don't believe there is a function for this right away, the only solution I can think of is to manually (specified in code) filter the statuses you don't need from the `wc_get_order_statuses()` function's output